# RichTextFX read-only?

Tags: javafx, richtextfx

I would like to use RichTextFX (StyledTextArea)  to print standard output with error messages et al.
I am already using it in it for my custom code editing, and It works well.

But how might I make the output "read only"?
I would like the user to be able to mark text, copy-and-paste, interact with links and have hover-over popups etc.  But not to be able to change the content of the output.

Should I perhaps implement some sort of change-listener which block/reverts any changes the user might (accidentally) make, or is there a simpler/more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StyledTextArea` has a `setEditable` method, so calling `setEditable(false)` should do what you need.